# tabbed content box with different tabbed background images

Tags: content

I am currently looking for a way to replicate the image I have below. I have come across many tabbed content plugin's and snippets of code, but I cannot figure out how to add different background images to each tab.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Prepare

You will have to use some *jQuery* and *jQuery UI* on your tabs.

Load it with `wp_enqueue_script` - [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), [How-To](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/05/06/adding-scripts-properly-to-wordpress-part-1-wp_enqueue_script/).

#### The search

[In any case: Google for "jQuery Tabs".](http://www.google.at/search?q=jQuery%20Tabs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

#### Mark up

The mark-up will look close to this one.

```
<!-- These are the tabs -->
<ul class="wpse-tabs">
    <li>
        <a href="#your-target-div-A" title="Your target description A">
            <span class="wpse-tabs-icon smilie-icon"></span>
            A: Some descriptive text
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#your-target-div-B" title="Your target description B">
            <span class="wpse-tabs-icon stats-icon"></span>
            B: Some descriptive text
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- This is your content with wrapper -->
<div class="tab-target-wrapper">
    <div id="your-target-div-A">Your content A</div>
    <div id="your-target-div-B">Your content B</div>
</div>
```

#### The Style

```
<style>
/* Assumin you're using an image sprite as background. 
In case you don't know what that is, ask google */
.wpse-tabs-icon {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url('iconsprite.png') no-repeat;
}
.smilie-icon {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.stats-icon {
    background-position: 20px 0px;
}
</style>
```